# how to remove a part of element of list in python

Tags: python, list, data-manipulation

i have been trying to find a way to get MAC address and device name from a string containing other useless data , i managed to remove the unnecessary data off that string but as the string contains more than one device name and MAC address i found it difficult get Device name and its MAC address in two different string or list.The string has data like:

'                  Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device_name1

```
               Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device_name2
               Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device_name3
```

'
I used this Code:

```
t= e.splitlines(True)
print(len(t),t)
```

I also use Split('\n')

All i get is this:

```
 226
 (16, [' \r\n', ' \r', '                        \r', ' Device 
 C4:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX name\r\n', ' \r', '                        \r', ' Device 
 55:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX name\r\n', ' \r', '                        \r', ' Device 
 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Name _XYXY\r\n', ' \r\n', '   \r\n', '  \r\n', ' \r', '                        
 \r', ' '])
```

After this i found it difficult to get Device name and MAC address into different string.
Using below code i was able to get MAC address form every Element of the list.

```
p = re.compile('(?:[0-9a-fA-F]:?){12}')
red = str(t)
ting = re.findall(p, red)   
print(ting)
```

But i am still trying to figure out a way to get Device name.i want get the name and MAC address of each device in different string as String1="Device name MAC address" string2="Device name MAC address".

Please do share your suggestion Thank you.

Comment: i solved this issue using list compression as ' ting ="Device"
        ding = "".join(s for s in t if ting in s) '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After splitting the lines, you'll need to split each line one by one. You can use an empty space as the separator.

You can use list comprehension to make this easy. For example, getting the MACs:

```
In [16]: devices = '''
    ...: Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device_name2
    ...: Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device_name3
    ...: '''

In [17]: [s.split(' ')[1] for s in devices.splitlines() if s]
Out[17]: ['XX:XX:XX:XX:XX', 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX']
```

Comment: this is useful but how to split the lines in the string because using  split() or splitlines()  converts string to list. after getting it into list i am not able to extract device name and MAC address. can you please tell me how to make each line into different string , Thank you!!

Comment: You can use join:
    ', '.join([s.split(' ')[1] for s in devices.splitlines() if s])

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be fitting for you to create a dictionary of the names with the adresses. It is possible to implicitly create string variables but I wouldn't recommend it, as a dictionary is safer and allows you to do the same things. A dictionary also allows you to parse through the devices, while if you would create separate string variables you would not be able to see which variables were created in a simple manner. This is how I would do it:

```
devices = '''
 Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device_name2
 Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device_name3
'''
dLines = devices.splitlines()

#If you want to make a dictionary:
devDict = dict([(device.split(' ')[3], device.split(' ')[2]) for device in dLines if device])
#Access specific adresses:
adress = devDict['Device_name2']

#If you want separate lists of names and adress:
adresses = [device.split(' ')[2] for device in dLines if device]
names = [device.split(' ')[3] for device in dLines if device]
```

This gives the following variables:

```
>>> devDict
{'Device_name2': 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX', 'Device_name3': 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'}
>>> devDict['Device_name2']
'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'
>>> names
['Device_name2', 'Device_name3']
>>> adresses
['XX:XX:XX:XX:XX', 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX']
```

Comment: it is useful but it will get complex if the number of Devices are increase, for my project i think it will be at least 12 devices.

Comment: It will do exactly the same thing whether you have 2 or 2000 devices. Making different strings for each on the other hand will get complex.